# puppeteer wait for page update after button click (no navigation)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Trying [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for the first time and it is amazing. 
I need to wait for a page to fetch and render new data after a button click. This does not cause a navigation (the url is the same) so the following code does not work (it gives timeout exception):

```
await Promise.all([
    myButton.click()
    page.waitForNavigation()
])
```

What's the correct way to wait for the page to fetch/render async data on click?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the DOM changes in some way, you can wait for a specific element or selector.

Maybe an image appears.

```js
await myButton.click();
await page.waitForSelector('img.success');
```

Maybe some element with an ID attribute is inserted into the DOM.

```js
await myButton.click();
await page.waitForSelector('#newElementThatAppeared');
```

If you're unfamiliar with DOM selectors, you can read up [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) and [here](https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/select-dom-elements-by-css-selector-4/). They're powerful and easy to use.

**Update** - Custom wait predicate.

If we always know the length...

```js
await myButton.click();
await page.waitFor(() => document.querySelectorAll('ul.specialList li').length > 5);
```

If we know the length will increase

```js
const listSize = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('ul.specialList li').length);
await myButton.click();
await page.waitFor(() => document.querySelectorAll('ul.specialList li').length > listSize);
```

Comment: Hi! The data fetched will update an already non empty list of <li>, so I am afraid I can’t rely on the presence of specific selector...maybe wait for the list to change size? But how?

Comment: Hmm. Could you update the question with a relevant snippet of the **before click** state of the DOM and the **after click** state? I may be able to help a bit more with those details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `await Promise.all` some kind of concurrency and if you need *click* and then *wait* split this with

```
await page.click('#selector');
const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(response => response.url() === 'https://example.com' && response.status() === 200);
return finalResponse.ok();
```

And be [noted](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.17.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions):

> This resolves when the page navigates to a new URL or reloads.

Comment: @Faltesek I fixed my typo, please remove your minus.

Comment: @Tom Faltesek Why your -1 needed under my answer? I try to help you try to troll?

Comment: Not trying to troll you. Just pointing out that the OP stated that the navigation and URL does **NOT** change. So your solution won't be helpful.

Comment: Answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, kind of an hack but didn't find any better solution for now.
Basically I am comparing the number of specific li elements before and after the button click to verify when new data has been loaded.

```
const wait = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

let data = await page.evaluate(_ => document.querySelectorAll("li.className").length) 

let isDataLoaded = false
await page.click("#myButton")

while(!isDataLoaded) {
    if (data.length !== await.page.evaluate(_ => document.querySelectorAll("li.className").length)) {
        isDataLoaded = true
    }
    await wait(100)
}

// new data should be loaded and rendered now in the page
// [...]
```

Comment: Instead of that while loop, could you just use the `waitFor` like in my last example?

Comment: `await page.waitFor(() => document.querySelectorAll('li.className').length != listSize);`

Comment: I think you have used an incorrect syntax:

await page.waitFor(listSize => document.querySelectorAll('li.className').length > listSize, {}, listSize)

this works, but from my tests this is slower respect to the while solution

Comment: I called my variable `listSize` in my example. You called it `data`. Is that the issue?

Comment: await page.waitFor(() => document.querySelectorAll('li.className').length !== data);

Comment: Even better, specifying the polling time between evaluation of the predicate, in milliseconds:

`await page.waitFor(listSize => document.querySelectorAll('li.className').length > listSize, {polling: 100}, listSize)`

This works basically the same as the while solution and probably is the way to go. Thanks!